# Stuck in a terminal tty - can't switch to another or break out of error

Tags: tty

I accidentally added a default route on my home server that disconnected me from it. No way to connect except on the console.

When I went to the console, it already had a guest console active. I went to switch to my own account where things got sour. Something went wrong and I ended up with a text console spitting out endless errors of:

```
bbswitch no suitable _dsm call found
```

This seems to be related to an error in nvidia graphical drivers according to short google search.

I can't break out of the error, and I can't get another tty using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>to<kbd>F7</kbd> (or just <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>to<kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>to<kbd>F7</kbd>).

Do I have any other option than manual restart?

Answer (score 0):

Select a different tty with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then use that console to fix your video card problem.

You can configure and change the video driver from the commandline with:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
$ sudo apt install nvidia-###
```

The first command checks the available drivers.  The last command selects the driver.  You might consider selecting the **recommended** driver.

Comment: The  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> either doesnt work or the same log stream is being sent to all tty's. Tried attaching display to all different ports and no difference. Ended up using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Sys rq</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> to reboot.

PS. Don't know why the keyboard shortcut is not working on the text display...

Comment: Do you have the same problem when booting to a Live USB?